# Generate multiple new pandas dataframes using lists and for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import rec, nan
df1=pd.DataFrame.from_records(rec.array([(202001L, 2020L, 'apples', 'CA', 100L),
         (202002L, 2020L, 'apples', 'CA', 150L),
         (202001L, 2020L, 'apples', 'USA', 400L),
         (202002L, 2020L, 'apples', 'USA', 675L),
         (202001L, 2020L, 'oranges', 'CA', 50L),
         (202002L, 2020L, 'oranges', 'CA', 65L),
         (202001L, 2020L, 'oranges', 'USA', 175L),
         (202002L, 2020L, 'oranges', 'USA', 390L)], 
                  dtype=[('yyyymm', '<i8'), ('year', '<i8'), ('prod', 'O'), ('country', 'O'), ('rev', '<i8')]))
```

I need to:

a) Take df1 & split by country...use country names from df1 to apply to create df2_CA, df2_USA.

b) Generate another 2 dfs showing total sales by year by product (example uses 2020, two months only), using suffix '_annual'...so we get df2_CA_annual, df2_USA_annual.

End result:
[image]

**Question:** My actual use case has a dozen cuts and I want to keep the coding compact.  I figure I can **save time using lists and for loops to create the final dfs** I want. How would this be done fixing the code below?

```
# 1. Get dfs by country: CA and USA...df2_(country):
    
for x in df1['country'].unique():
       locals()['df2_' + x ] = df1[(df1['country'] == x ) ]
        
#2. Take dfs from step 1, calculate total revenue by year.  Create frames df2_(country)_annual:        
    
mylist=[df2_CA, df2_USA]
                     
for x in mylist['country'].unique():  
      locals()[ 'df2_' + x + '_annual' ] = mylist[(mylist['country'] == x )]   
      x = x.groupby(['year', 'prod','country']).sum()[["rev"]]
```

Comment: Do you really want your output DF's named that way? It couldn't be just a list of DF's?

Comment: I'm open to whatever works...

Comment: Cool , then check out below answer, You almost did everything yourself. Hope that is what you are looking for. If not let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach to @VMSMani 's answer would be to leverage dictionaries:

```py
df_annual = {}
for c in df1['country'].unique():
    df_annual[c] = df1.where(df1['country'] == c).groupby(['year', 'prod', 'country']).sum()[['rev']]
```

the "only" difference would be that you store all the dataframes by key, so you can get them back at a later point by just calling `df_annual[country]`, which I suppose keeps things tidier.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need list of DF's then below might help:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import rec, nan

df1=pd.DataFrame.from_records(rec.array([(202001, 2020, 'apples', 'CA', 100),
         (202002, 2020, 'apples', 'CA', 150),
         (202001, 2020, 'apples', 'USA', 400),
         (202002, 2020, 'apples', 'USA', 675),
         (202001, 2020, 'oranges', 'CA', 50),
         (202002, 2020, 'oranges', 'CA', 65),
         (202001, 2020, 'oranges', 'USA', 175),
         (202002, 2020, 'oranges', 'USA', 390)], 
                  dtype=[('yyyymm', '<i8'), ('year', '<i8'), ('prod', 'O'), ('country', 'O'), ('rev', '<i8')]))

final_df_list = list()
for col in df1.country.unique():
    final_df_list.append(df1.where(df1.country == col).groupby(['year', 'prod','country']).sum()[["rev"]])
```

Comment: Thanks...how do I view the the results in final_df_list as a dataframe?

Comment: You can loop through the list or if you just want view print(final_df_list).

Comment: Suppose I want a df something life df_annual_result = df = pd.DataFrame(...) is this how you would convert final_df_list?

Comment: if i need to further work on the final_df_list , i would do something like "for df in final_df_list: df.columns"  now you have the expected dataframe which you can reference with df and perform your further actions